# How to read specified row in csv file

Tags: java, file, csv, opencsv

I have daily data starting from 1980 in csv file. But I want to read data only from 1985. Because the other dataset in another file starts from 1985. How can I skip reading the data before 1985 in Java?

Comment: Read line by line and skip the ones that are before 1985?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you having problems? Please show the essential code with which you are having problems.

Comment: How do you read it? With stream? You split it? Does every row have a fixed size? You need to post more details

Comment: Reading .csv fille by using file reader class,yes every row is fixed size

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to use the [grep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep) command line utility to filter data instead of developing a custom solution.

```
grep 1985 *.csv > data_from_1985.csv
```

If you need a better expression to filter your data to avoid spuroius data you can use [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) to test it.

for example, if the lines in your CSV start with the year, you may use

```
grep "^1985" *.csv > data_from_1985.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

read opencsv doc: http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/#how-to-read

read each line (from example):

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("yourfile.csv"));
 String [] nextLine;
 while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
    // nextLine[] is an array of values from the line
    System.out.println(nextLine[0] + nextLine[1] + "etc...");
 }
```

convert to int

```
int one_value=Integer.parseInt(nextLine[i]); // iterate i
```

then, get your "year" column, and compare it to 1985

Comment: @MadhuSudhanBaddam . Your year is certainly defined in one column. You didnt precise your csv structure.

Comment: Madhu - Guillaume is correct.  Yes you want to read rows but you want to filter based on a column value.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this [link](http://way2java.com/io/skipping-a-part-of-a-file/) can help you.  It talks about the seek() function of InputStream.

You could calculate in witch byte starts the 1985 data, and skip this bytes with seek().

Comment: link only answers are of poor quality as the link itself can become unavailable in the future...

Comment: I explained the solution, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Madhu - if you are using openCSV then look at the javadocs for the [CSVToBeanFilter](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/opencsv/bean/CsvToBeanFilter.html).  This will give you a good example of how to parse a file reading only the rows who column(s) match given criteria.